# any alternative SQL for flutter rather than sqflite

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I was wonder if there any alternative way to store offline data in dependencies database rather than using sqflite!! 
if any one knows any SQL or even nosql libraries for flutter that's is not complicated like sqflite please mention it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a alternative, use a NoSql database.

**Sembast**

Yet another NoSQL persistent store database solution for single process io applications. The whole document based database resides in a single file and is loaded in memory when opened. Changes are appended right away to the file and the file is automatically compacted when needed.

Works on Dart VM and Flutter (no plugin needed, 100% Dart). Inspired from IndexedDB, DataStore, WebSql, NeDB, Lawndart...

Supports encryption using user-defined codec.

**This is a link when you can get the library:** 
https://pub.dev/packages/sembast

Comment: Another option is Hive: https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Comment: HIVE is a great option, I use it in different projects and the result is amazing

Comment: question is about a sql database an alternate for a sql must be a sql , why are you suggesting a NoSql????

Comment: Recently i using another database https://pub.dev/packages/isar this is a great solution to use in local database